# Переставить слова в строке по алфавиту и переставить слова по убыванию количества негласных букв

Tags: c

Задание

> Переставить слова в строке по алфавиту и переставить слова по убыванию
>   количества негласных букв. Просидел пару дней и ничего не могу
>   придумать, в литературе тоже ничего

Как разбивать строку на лексемы я понял:

```
char *pch = strtok(s," ,."); 

while (pch != NULL) 
{
    s2[k]=pch;
    k++;
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
}
```

А как разбить эти лексемы на отдельные знаки?

Answer (score 0):

> А как разбить эти лексемы на отдельные знаки?

Зачем?

> переставить слова в строке по алфавиту

[man strcoll](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=strcoll&category=3&russian=)

> переставить слова по убыванию количества негласных букв

Для этого достаточно посчитать количество согласных в каждом слове. В самом простейшем случае, без учёта локали и только для латиницы:

```
size_t consonants( const char *word ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    while( word && *word ) {
        if( isalpha( *word ) && !strchr( "aeiouyAEIOUY", *word ) ) {
            ++n;
        }
        ++word;
    }
    return n;
}
```

---

Ну, как-то так, навскидку:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DELIMITERS  "\n\r\t ;.,:"

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
static int w_compare( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const char *pa = *(char * const *)a;
    const char *pb = *(char * const *)b;

    return strcoll( pa, pb );
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
int main()
{
    char src[] = "zzzz c bbb aaa baab a ccc arrraa b";
    size_t words_count = 0, i;
    char **words = NULL;

    /*
     * 0. Создаём копию строки для работы.
     */
    char *tmp = strdup( src );

    /*
     * 1. Считаем количество слов:
     */
    char *word = strtok( tmp, DELIMITERS );
    while( word ) {
        ++words_count;
        word = strtok( NULL, DELIMITERS );
    }

    if( words_count ) {
        /*
         * 2) сохраняем слова в массиве:
         */
        words = calloc( sizeof(char *), words_count );
        strcpy( tmp, src );
        word = strtok( tmp, DELIMITERS );
        i = 0;
        while( word ) {
            words[i++] = word;
            word = strtok( NULL, DELIMITERS );
        }

        for( i = 0; i < words_count; ++i ) {
            printf( "%s\n", words[i] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );

        /*
         * 3. Сортируем массив
         */
        qsort( words, words_count, sizeof(char *), w_compare );
        for( i = 0; i < words_count; ++i ) {
            printf( "%s\n", words[i] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    else {
        printf( "No words found!\n" );
    }
    free( words );
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Как добавить сортировку по согласным, и как слить в строку - оставим
 * на продолжение домашки :)
 */
```

Comment: Я так и не понял как переставлять слова, то что оно сравнивает строки какой толк?

Comment: @БодяКБ, отсортируйте список полученных слов по обоим критериям, потом слейте его в новую строку. При необходимости - скопируйте её на место исходной.

Comment: так как я сортировал, то оно сортировало только по размеру слова, а как по алфавиту сделать я не знаю

Comment: Так написал же: man strcoll